# Stretch page to always be 100% height?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm creating a webpage in Twitter Bootstrap (if it matters) and I want the page to be 100%; in height, so there won't be **any** empty space on the bottom or the top of the page, as it looks like this now:

[image]

And I want it to look like this:

[image]

While long pages shouldn't have any extra whitespace in the container and it would be still 100% in height like this:

[image]

But how I can achieve this? As the layout is liquid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use display: table and display: table-row. For older browsers that don't support display: table you can use Modernizr and a jQuery fallback. Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/85FHe/11/

For more information on CSS table display support go to http://caniuse.com/css-table.

Comment: Bootstrap is actually using modernizr (or atleast Roots-theme == Bootstrap for wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
    <body>
      <div id="fill">
        <div id="content"></div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

your CSS will be like

```
#content{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: black;
    display: block;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#fill { 
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
​
```

Comment: Nope. And this would break the liquid layout.

Answer (score 0):

This requires jquery but seemed to work fine to get the whole page no mater the screen size well at least work for me.

```
    var height = $(window).height();
    var cssheight = String(height)
    $('#tabs-1').css('height', cssheight);
```